# Canvas or SVG UI Components

Tags: user-interface, html, canvas, svg

I want to build a web app using either canvas or SVG. But I would like to use a library that gives me some pre-made ui components like file menus or forms.

What are some of the libraries out there that could accomplish this with either of these technologies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mocha ui uses Canvas and is probably the closest to having good file menus and forms: http://mochaui.org/

Some other things to look at:

http://raphaeljs.com/ - Raphael for SVG

https://bespin.mozillalabs.com/ - Mozilla Bespin premade code editor for Canvas

Comment: Old question and answer, but to make it more complete, you should add Zebra UI to this list. http://www.zebkit.org and it looks like Mocha UI link is dead now.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use HTML for the widgets, then have a look at the [pergola framework](http://www.dotuscomus.com/pergola/examples.html) which is based on svg (has menus, windows, widgets etc).

Comment: The link was 404, here is an examples link that works: http://www.dotuscomus.com/pergola/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the canvas based framework

http://www.zebkit.com

Zebra brings fresh view and possibilities to develop WEB based Rich UI applications. The approach sits on top of HTML5 Canvas element what makes possible to render any imaginable UI. Zebra development is much closer to software engineering where you write well structured, supportable, extendable code basing on easy Zebra OOP concept